# How to split values of a map in terraform to create lists?

Tags: dictionary, terraform

I have a map variable with many values (NACL rules). I am trying to add rules accordingly

```
variable "rules" {
  default = {
    a = "200,false,tcp,allow,0.0.0.0/0,23,23"
    b = "100,true,tcp,allow,0.0.0.0/0,1024,65535"
  }
}


resource "aws_network_acl_rule" "bar" {
  network_acl_id = "<id>"
  rule_number    = "${split(",",element(values(var.rules),count.index))[0]}"
  egress         = "${split(",",element(values(var.rules),count.index))[1]}"
  protocol       = "${split(",",element(values(var.rules),count.index))[2]}"
  rule_action    = "${split(",",element(values(var.rules),count.index))[3]}"
  cidr_block     = "${split(",",element(values(var.rules),count.index))[4]}"
  from_port      = "${split(",",element(values(var.rules),count.index))[5]}"
  to_port        = "${split(",",element(values(var.rules),count.index))[6]}"
  count          = "${length(values(var.rules))}"
}
```

Error:
`expected "}" but found "["`

Since maps with lists as values aren't supported, I am trying to split the values and iterate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simpler way to deal with the map `rules`

```
variable "rules" {
  default = {
   "0" = "200,false,tcp,allow,0.0.0.0/0,23,23"
   "1" = "100,true,tcp,allow,0.0.0.0/0,1024,65535"
  }
}

resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_network_acl" "bar" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"
}

resource "aws_network_acl_rule" "bar" {
  count          = "${length(var.rules)}"
  network_acl_id = "${aws_network_acl.bar.id}"
  rule_number    = "${element(split(",",var.rules[count.index]),0)}"
  egress         = "${element(split(",",var.rules[count.index]),1)}"
  protocol       = "${element(split(",",var.rules[count.index]),2)}"
  rule_action    = "${element(split(",",var.rules[count.index]),3)}"
  cidr_block     = "${element(split(",",var.rules[count.index]),4)}"
  from_port      = "${element(split(",",var.rules[count.index]),5)}"
  to_port        = "${element(split(",",var.rules[count.index]),6)}"
}
```

If you insist to use old map, key is "a,b,...", you need to adjust resource to

```
variable "rules" {
  default = {
    "a" = "200,false,tcp,allow,0.0.0.0/0,23,23"
    "b" = "100,true,tcp,allow,0.0.0.0/0,1024,65535"
  }
}

resource "aws_network_acl_rule" "bar" {
  count          = "${length(var.rules)}"
  network_acl_id = "${aws_network_acl.bar.id}"
  rule_number    = "${element(split(",",element(values(var.rules),count.index)),0)}"
  egress         = "${element(split(",",element(values(var.rules),count.index)),1)}"
  protocol       = "${element(split(",",element(values(var.rules),count.index)),2)}"
  rule_action    = "${element(split(",",element(values(var.rules),count.index)),3)}"
  cidr_block     = "${element(split(",",element(values(var.rules),count.index)),4)}"
  from_port      = "${element(split(",",element(values(var.rules),count.index)),5)}"
  to_port        = "${element(split(",",element(values(var.rules),count.index)),6)}"
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Another option, easier to read, is with `lookup()`:

```
variable "rules" {
  default = [
    {
      rule_number = 200
      egress = false
      protocol = "tcp"
      rule_action = "allow"
      cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
      from_port= 23
      to_port = 23
    },
    {
      rule_number = 100
      egress = true
      procotol = "tcp"
      rule_action = "allow"
      cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
      from_port = 1024
      to_port = 65535
    },
  ]
}

resource "aws_network_acl_rule" "bar" {
  count          = "${length(var.rules)}"
  network_acl_id = "<id>"
  rule_number    = "${lookup(var.rules[count.index], "rule_number")}"
  egress         = "${lookup(var.rules[count.index], "egress")}"
  protocol       = "${lookup(var.rules[count.index], "protocol")}"
  rule_action    = "${lookup(var.rules[count.index], "rule_action")}"
  cidr_block     = "${lookup(var.rules[count.index], "cidr_block")}"
  from_port      = "${lookup(var.rules[count.index], "from_port")}"
  to_port        = "${lookup(var.rules[count.index], "to_port")}"
}
```